# Social network directed graph library for .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, drawing, social-networking

I am on a project where I have multiple users of a portal and they are connected to other users of the portal. Now we are asked to draw a **“Social Network” relationship graph** to see the relationships. The constraint is that **this graph has to be seen in the web browser**.

The graph has to be something like:
[image: Icons connected by blue lines, components grouped together]

Is there any C# library or component to draw this type of graphs? We have already checked these:

- http://flare.prefuse.org/
- http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yfiles_practicalinfo_gallery.html
- [.NET graph library around?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578493/net-graph-library-around)
- http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/
- https://graphsharp.codeplex.com/
- http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/f1303e46-965f-401a-87c3-34e1331d32c5/default.aspx
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/zedgraph/

But I want to check if you already used some other and your feedback.

Comment: A perfect example where a Fractal Layout algorithm fits perfectly (Mind Fusion NetDiagram - http://www.mindfusion.eu/features-netdiagram.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've used [Northwoods Go.NET](http://nwoods.com) for many years and it has been great.

Comment: Northwoods also has a WPF library: http://nwoods.com/components/silverlight-wpf/goxam-overview.htm

Answer (score 3):

I've used Microsoft chart it's fine and free !

Maybe you can take a look to graphviz too : http://www.graphviz.org/

Answer (score 2):

It can be expensive but [Tom Sawyer Visualization, ActiveX edition](http://www.tomsawyer.com/products/visualization.activex/index.php) is a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Another great product I just stumbled across with HTML5 (canvas/SVG) support:

- http://www.mindfusion.eu/features-netdiagram.html

They also have a pure client-side JavaScript library also with HTML5 support:

- http://www.mindfusion.eu/jsdiagram.html