# C# graphs algorithms library

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, graph

I'm looking for .NET library with the next graphs algorithms:

- algorithm for finding a minimum
  spanning tree;
- algorithm for partitioning graph for N subgraphs with minimal number of connections.

I can write my own realization, but don't have too much time. Tell me, please, names of any existing libraries that can do this. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET graph library around?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578493/net-graph-library-around)

Comment: [QuickGraph](http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/)

Comment: @JasonTrue, I don't need graphic capabilities and I'm looking for another algorithms.

Comment: You should read the answers to the other question more carefully, then. The graph libraries mentioned are primarily about the algorithms, though the other person wanted visualization in addition to the algorithms. QuickGraph, the accepted answer on that question, is what you want.

Comment: Ok, I have read another post and looked at QuickGraph. But I found only finding a minimum spanning tree algorithms...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution was to use `QuickGraph` library. It already has algorithm for finding a minimum spanning tree. And I used their implementation of graph to write my own algorithm for partitioning it.

Answer (score 1):

[yWorks](http://www.yworks.com/en/index.html) provides [several products for .NET](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yfiles_dotnetplatform_about.html)
Depending on where you plan on deploying you can choose your flavor and perform [lots of analyses](http://docs.yworks.com/yfileswpf/Index.html?topic=dguide/yFilesDGLayout/analysis.html) on the graph.
Although I'm not fond of the API (a bit too java-ish), the biggest disadvantage is definitely the price.