# Graph out message flow in a service oriented architecture (using NServiceBus)

Tags: reflection, graphics, graph, soa, nservicebus

I have a large service oriented system that's using NServiceBus as a messaging bus. I need to produce a graph/flow diagram of where messages are sent, where they're handled, etc.

My plan was to run through the compiled binaries of the system, use reflection to find messages, find where they're sent, find their handlers, and graph the whole thing.

Can anyone recommend a toolkit for producing complex-ish graphs?

Comment: I'm using some components from NQueueStuffer, and will try to plug that into a graphing library and see how that fares :)

Comment: Interesting subject, please lets us know if you find a good solution!

Comment: Have you checked out the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578493/net-graph-library-around or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44090/do-you-know-any-graph-visualization-libraries-for-net?

Answer (score 0):

Try giraph from apache, is able to handle very complex diagrams, with huge nodes and/or relationships between them.

Regards,
Jose

Answer (score 0):

We've now added a couple of tools (ServiceInsight and ServicePulse) that provide a UI on top of a backend we've created (called ServiceControl) that feeds off of the audit queue.

These UI tools show the graph of message flows, as well as enabling you to send failed messages back for reprocessing (among other things).

For more info, check out: http://particular.net/ServiceInsight-1