# Graphs used to compare two datasets

Tags: c#

I have two data sets, each dataset contains the pixel values of an image. I need to verify the difference of two datasets is a linear or something like that.

Which open libraries can be used to draw graph to compare two datasets using C#?

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578493/net-graph-library-around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been using this Compare .NET Objects on codeplex.

http://comparenetobjects.codeplex.com/

I use it more for testing when I need to assert the equality of two complex objects.