# How to get a version tree for a file in git?

Tags: git, clearcase, version-tree

In clearcase I could just run

```
branchlocation>cleartool vtree <filename>
```

And a version tree would pop up showing me the merges for that file. I want to do the equivalent in git.

I think it is something to do with `git read-tree` - but that doesn't look like what I'm looking for.

My question is: **How to get a version tree for a file in git?**

Comment: Do you mean all changes for a particular file? `git log -- <filename>`

Comment: `gitk <filename>` but prepare to be disappointed and confused

Comment: Thanks Andrew - can you expand that into an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The **[`gitk`](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitk)** approach was mentioned in "[Git Version Tree: Gitk](http://www.philforhumanity.com/Git_Version_Tree.html)"

> The problem with this command is that the output can easily become too large and complex to be easily readable.
>   If that is the case, then you might want to run `gitk` on a single file to only see the changes on that file. For example:

```
gitk --all FILENAME &
```

The closest I have seen from a ClearCase  version tree in Git is in "[Viewing full version tree in git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18287861/6309)", which took:

```
git log --oneline --graph --color --all --decorate
```

And transformed it with [`crc8/GitVersionTree`](https://github.com/crc8/GitVersionTree) into:

[image: https://camo.githubusercontent.com/0cf835a38473b6caa9b39fe59a7088d3dcb70f09/68747470733a2f2f7261772e6769746875622e636f6d2f637263382f47697456657273696f6e547265652f6d61737465722f73616d706c655f6776742e706e67]

You also have graph tools which could help, mentioned in "[How do I build a version tree for a Git repository using LibGit2(Sharp)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15225477/6309)"

Comment: Thanks VonC - you've been right onto all my clearcase questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
gitk --all $file
gitk --all $dir
```