# Interactive Flowchart Like Code Map in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, interactive, visio, flowchart, code-map

I am looking for a tool to make a clickable flowchart. Very much like the Code Map found in Visual Studio (I've been using 2015 Enterprise).
[image]

I want to have the clickable boxes to see more detailed content, but for any kind of flowchart diagram, not just code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's lot of solutions for creating this kinds of diagrams and flowcharts available:

See [here for .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578493/net-graph-library-around),

[here for Javascript/HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034/graph-visualization-library-in-javascript)

[here for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162618/java-graph-library-for-dynamic-visualisation?lq=1)

Visual Studio is probably using [MS' own](https://github.com/Microsoft/automatic-graph-layout) implementation.

JetBrains' Resharper Visual Studio plugin uses [yFiles WPF](http://www.yworks.com/yfileswpf)

Comment: Indeed, Visual Studio uses MSAGL https://github.com/Microsoft/automatic-graph-layout

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the amazingly late reply :/